# How to get macAddress using reactjs or gettting error in package

Tags: javascript, office-addins, add-in, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I want to use macAddress in reactJS Component. But when I am using the getmac package i am getting error.
Can any one help me to do this or refer any documentation about macAddress.
[Package Error]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV0hr.png

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac) for the module you are using.

> This library will not run in web browsers / on the client-side / in webpack / in browserify / in angular / in react / in jQuery / in HTML. It will only run on Node.js environments, which the web browser is not.

---

There is no API in the browser that will expose the machine's MAC addresses to client-side JavaScript.

The closest you could come would be to write a web service (in the server-side programming language of your choice) which looked up the MAC address from the IP address the request came from. This would only work within a **local network** environment.